# About django ModelBase code

Tags: python, django, metaclass

I'm reading the source code of django, mainly about the Model.

```
in class ModelBase code
##########################

def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
    super_new = super(ModelBase, cls).__new__

    # Also ensure initialization is only performed for subclasses of Model
    # (excluding Model class itself).
    parents = [b for b in bases if isinstance(b, ModelBase)]
    if not parents:
        return super_new(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    # Create the class.
    module = attrs.pop('__module__')
    new_class = super_new(cls, name, bases, {'__module__': module})
    attr_meta = attrs.pop('Meta', None)
    abstract = getattr(attr_meta, 'abstract', False)
    if not attr_meta:
        meta = getattr(new_class, 'Meta', None)
    else:
        meta = attr_meta
    base_meta = getattr(new_class, '_meta', None)
```

I'm curious about the:

```
    base_meta = getattr(new_class, '_meta', None)
```

Since the new_class was generated by

```
   new_class = super_new(cls, name, bases, {'__module__': module})
```

I think the new_class will only have attribute '**module**', where could it get a '_meta' attribute?

So In fact my problem cames to "in the metaclass.**new**, how are the attributes passed in assembled? and how are the generated type instance's attributes assembled?". I did a google work and I understand the calling sequence a little, but these details are still unknown.

Comment: If one of the class in bases has these attributes then `getattr` will surely find them.

Comment: This new operator is meant to work recursively. So when analyzing it you need to consider both if this is one of the first evaluations or any of the later ones.  In other words `super_new` may very well be the same `__new__()` definition.